# Appending hidden element from outside form to inside form html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am trying to append an element that contains input from outside a form and appending it to a element within a form for submission. The element is hidden to act as a template, but when appended it clones the hidden element and removes the hidden component for input and submission purposes.

Here is an example of the html section:

```
<div class="samplesinfo hidden">
  <label>User input</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Insert usr input">
</div>

<button id="addsmplbtn">Add Sample</button>

<hr>

<form>
  <div class="paste">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Followed by the jQuery for removal and appending of the hidden element:

```
$("#addsmplbtn").click(function() {
        var element = $(".samplesinfo.hidden").clone(true);
        element.removeClass("hidden").insertAfter("#paste:last");
}
```

When clicking the add sample button is does append the template element, but not within the form under the "paste" id as per script. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited and it works. change `"#paste:last"` to `".paste:last"` then it works.

Comment: Mine answer should solve it then too ... If that is right it would be nice to accept it.

Comment: You should not edit the question to fix it, always leave the question as it is and provide suggestions in comments and solutions in answers. Only edit question to add more information about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your div have class="paste" instead id="paste".

Comment: Please see my edit, it was just an example script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the script was working, however the with updating the javascript linked file to the html file made no changes to the functionality of the page. Once I added the JS to the html file as part of script tags, the script worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
var element = $(".samplesinfo.hidden").clone(true);
        element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(".paste");
```